# Is it possible to convert a numpy array to a csv file and then load it back as a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, reshape

I have a dataset of images. I have successfully iterated through my directories and subdirectories to store the images into numpy array.

I have used the following statement:

```py
Image_array = np.array(Image_array)
```

My array size is: 100x224x224

This works fine and the images get stored properly. However, I am now trying to save this numpy array into a CSV file. I have flattened the numpy array and have saved it in an array.csv file as shown below:

```py
array = array.flatten('F')
np.savetxt('array.csv', array, delimiter=',', fmt='%d')
```

The above code just creates 1 CSV file, with one column with the pixel values.

I then attempted to read the CSV data back into a numpy array but the data is heavily messed up when loading as the image is just blurred. The array also displays with '.' after each number which it was not doing prior.

```py
filename = "array.csv"
data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',')
new= np.array((data).reshape(100,224,224),order='F')
```

Am I missing something? please assist?

Comment: `np.save/load` will easily save and reload the array, but the file isn't text.  To use `csv` you have to make  your array 2d, and apply a reshape after loading.  `arr.reshape(100,224*224)` is a possible reshape.  Or if you want more rows than columns `(100*224, 224)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I then attempted to read the csv data back into a numpy array but the data is heavily messed up

Don't use `order` parameter or use it consistently. You first flatten it with `F` but you didn't specify order parameter when reshaping it back, which defaults to `C`. I think you tried to do it but `order` parameter placed in wrong function, it should be inside `reshape`.

> The array also displays with '.' after each number which it was not doing prior.

Read the data with the same `dtype` as your prior matrix like `data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', dype=int)`. Since you didn't give a `dtype` it is converted to `float` I think.

Answer (score 0):

Np.flatten() creates a 1D array (which gives one csv instead of 100). Try splitting the images first and iterating through them, like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(100, 244, 244)
images = [x[i,:,:] for i in range(100)]
```

then your images come out like images[1], images [36], etc so you can save them like this

```
    def makelist():
        set = []
        for i in range(100):
            set.append(f"array{i}.csv")
        return set
    files = makelist()

    for file in files:
        for image in images:
            np.savetxt(file, image)
```